# Get Index from for loop looping inside NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am trying to get the index from the for loop while looping inside [NSManagedObject] I tried below code. anyone has idea how to get it.

**Error** : Type '[NSManagedObject]?' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'

```
    for (index, item) in RestaurantQuestions.all() {

        print(index) // should print index
       //Doing my stuff

    }
```

is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.enumerate()` to do so in Swift 2.0 and over as following :

```
for (index, item) in RestaurantQuestions.all()!.enumerate() {
    print(index) // should print index
    //Do your stuff
}
```

It returns a tuple with index and the value for each item in the array.
However `RestaurantQuestions.all()` must return a valid array in this case.

Comment: use @slava's solution it handles your optional array

Answer (score 5):

Probably that is because of optional type. Try to get rid of optionals like that:

```
if let questions = RestaurantQuestions.all() {
    for (index, item) in questions.enumerate() {
        print(index) // should print index
        //Doing my stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: nice answer but I'm already getting rid of optionals. I already accepted the answer but i have upvoted your two answers.